# Looking for an adapter to go from HDMI to RCA Component 480p

Tags: hdmi, television

**Request:** I want a box which converts from HDMI or VGA to Component 480p without introducing noticeable lag.

*Additional information which describes my situation:*

I have a decent "Flat Glass" CRT SD TV which I believe supports 480p Component Input.  I recall playing SOCOM II on PS2 with component cables and enabling that mode.  Anyway, I have some older computers and laptops, and looking to use this old TV as a monitor for emulation.

I'm looking for a device or solution which would add minimal lag since I'm planning to do some GBA/SNES Emulation.  I'm open to outputting VGA from my laptop and converting that instead.  Sound isn't an issue, as I can just use the mini-jack for that.  Also, if important, I'm planning to use a Debian Linux based system, probably a version of Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for any hardware ideas or solutions.

Comment: Looking for this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=hdmi%20to%20component%20converter&Submit=ENE

Comment: And there is this too: https://www.amazon.com/CableWholesale-Component-Video-Adapter-30H1-50200/dp/B00JMC9CLK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know everything there is to know about video signals, but given that your TV probably only takes analog inputs, I'm going to suggest the **[White PC VGA to AV TV RCA S-Video Converter Switch Box Adapter](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4UB3X34235)** here. Not only is this cheaper than HDMI alternatives, it has a better chance (in my imperfect opinion) of having less latency, because converting VGA to RCA signal is a totally analog process and so (I'm guessing) much simpler to do. I also like that you can power it from a USB port; a nice bonus feature that makes the whole setup a little less byzantine.

There are HDMI to VGA/3.5mm converter boxes out there, but the ones I could find mentioned ~1s latency, which I would find unacceptable for gaming.